# Flutter Firestore complex filter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore and it works great, my problem is when I try to make a complex filter.
I know the limitation regarding the filter with Firestore.
How can I make a filter like in the image with Firestore or a WorkAround[image: Filter exemple]

What i did until now:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection')
.where('date', arrayContainsAny: ['date1','date2','date3'])
.where('hastag', arrayContainsAny: ['music','festival'])
.where('rating', isEqualTo: '40')
.where('price', isGreaterThan: '100')
.where('price', isLessThan: '100')
```

But, i can't use arrayContainsAny twice. How can i achieve this filter?

Comment: Did you try anything already? It's much more likely that someone here can help if we see what you've tried already/how you tried to implement this?

Comment: As you've already noticed, you can only have one `array-contains` clause in a query. You will either have to merge all possible combinations of values into a single array, or you will have to perform one of the filters inside your application code.

Answer (score 0):

As @frank-van-puffelen has stated, you can only have one "arrayContainsAny" in a query.
However, you can use Dart for these kinds of filters (I would recommend using it on whichever one of the filters is most likely to exclude a lesser amount of results), for example:

```
var listOfHashTags= ['music','festival'];
yourList.where((document) => listOfHashTags.contains(document.hashtag)).toList();
```

Personally, I would err on the side of caution, putting both the "date" filter and the "hashtag" filter into their own lists, checking which is longer, and using that for the query and the other one for the Dart "where" function (you could also use Firebase Analytics to try and figure out which of the two filters more on average, but that will take testing)